# dc.js - Defining your own filter callback

Tags: dc.js

When you interact with one of the graphs DC takes whatever it is you click on (row, pie slice, etc) and passes that into crossfilter to get it to filter filter those records having that value.  Is there a way to tell DC.js that I'd want to use a custom function instead?

On this page https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_filter it shows that you can do this but I know that DC.js abstracts that away.  I've looked around the DC.js API but wasn't able to find anything along these lines.  Is it possible?

thnx,
Christoph

Comment: [filterHandler](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filterHandler__anchor)?

Comment: Actually, that's not quite what I'm looking for but it's really, really close.  What I was hoping to find is a way to use a custom function for testing whether a particular record matches a filter.  E.g., use indexOf on the value to determine whether it would produce a match

Comment: You can supply a custom function - look at the `filterFunction` section of the default handler in the docs. The only limitation is that the filter function is only passed the key - this is intrinsic to how crossfilter works. So you might need to define your dimension key function to supply you whatever fields you want.

Comment: Here's a simple example that came up yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57575866/676195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of what I'm looking for is by using the .filterHandler() function on the chart.

https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filterHandler__anchor